# Add IDs To HTML Table Code String

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, dom

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I have exported as an HTML file.  The Excel file has 'defined names' for some of the cells. I would like to somehow open the exported HTML file, then read through the Excel file defined names collection and give the corresponding HTML table cells an ID that I can parse back to the Excel file's defined name.  Once the cells have been given IDs (and a runat="server" attribute), I want to write the modified HTML out as a string/file so I can stuff it into my ASP page.

Can anybody tell me a way to go about this?  I thought I would be able to use the System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable class, then just stuff my exported HTML code into the InnerHtml property and be off to the races.  Alas, the InnerHtml property is not valid (write OR read) for the HtmlTable (or HtmlTableRow, but it IS valid for the HtmlTableCell for some reason).

There has to be a way to do this since, just pasting the exported HTML into an aspx page in the VS IDE, then adding id="MyTable" and runat="server" to the `<table>` tag will immediately give me an HtmlTable object that I can use in the context of the page.

I'm obviously not asking for fully fleshed out and working code, just a few lines to get me started.  Please don't kill me for my crime of ignorance!

If it helps, which I seriously doubt, this is a sample of what comes out of Excel when exported:

```html
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=856 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:642pt'>
 <tr class=xl1527583 height=30 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:22.5pt'>
  <td colspan=4 height=30 class=xl13127583 width=442 style='border-right:.5pt solid black;
  height:22.5pt;width:331pt'><a name="RANGE!A1:G197">BLAH FORM</a></td>
  <td class=xl6427583 width=91 style='border-left:none;width:68pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6527583 width=62 style='width:47pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl6527583 width=261 style='width:196pt'>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class=xl1527583 height=21 style='height:15.75pt'>
  <td colspan=4 height=21 class=xl13427583 style='border-right:.5pt solid black;
  height:15.75pt'>Title:</td>
  <td colspan=3 rowspan=3 class=xl11527583 width=414 style='border-right:.5pt solid black;
  border-bottom:.5pt solid black;width:311pt'><font class="font827583">BLAH 
  Management System<br>
    Document Number:</font><font class="font927583"><br>
    12.3.456A</font></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

There are ~4300 lines in the exported HTML - 2600 of those are style info.  They will be occasionally changing this form and I don't want to keep rebuilding it every time they do.

Comment: @Singh I don't have any code - I am completely stumped!

Answer (score 1):

Not being one with the ability to wait around for the *right* way to do things, here is what I came up with.  As I noted, the VS IDE pretty obviously has an HTML parser built into it that would work perfectly well for my purpose if I could only figure out where it 'lived' outside of the VS IDE and how to access if from my code.  I decided to try to use that in the only way I know how at the moment.  I pasted my exported HTML code into a new aspx web form page.  Then I created the Page_Init event handling code shown below.

```
// This is not absolutely necessary, but you may want to include it
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

  protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    StringWriter strWtr;
    StringBuilder sbldr;
    HtmlTextWriter htmlWtr;

    // Put in table modifying code here
    this.tbl_Mine.Rows[0].ID = "r1";
    this.tbl_Mine.Rows[0].Cells[0].ID = "r1c1";
    sbldr = new StringBuilder();
    strWtr = new StringWriter(sbldr);
    htmlWtr = new HtmlTextWriter(strWtr);

    this.tbl_Mine.RenderControl(htmlWtr);
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\HtmlTblMod.htm", sbldr.ToString());
  }
```

When launched, the page will write out my desired updates so I can paste them in to the real aspx page.  While this works, there has **GOT** to be a better way to get it done...  Anybody suggesting a sane approach to this task will get their answer accepted.